# How to Mock Async Functions Called From Other Functions in JEST?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

Maybe this question has been asked multiple times. But in my case, this is different (I think).

I can't mock an async function that called inside another function I want to test. I tried `mockImplementation`, `mockResolvedValue`, etc. Nothing changed.
Any idea what's wrong with my codeflow below?

There are 3 files involved in this case: test file, function file, helper file

**Helper File**:

```
export async function checkIfUserAllowed() {
   if (!allowed) throw new Error('Not Allowed')
}
```

**Function File**:

```
export async function GetData(user) {
   await checkIfUserAllowed();
   return true;
}
```

**Test File**:

```
const spyHelper = jest.spyOn(helper, 'checkIfUserAllowed')

describe('when user getting data', () => {
   it('should return data', async () => {
      spyHelper.mockResolvedValue() // <-- this is not working, still calls real function
      const res = await GetData('Brian')
      expect(res).toBeTruthy();
   })

   it('should return data', async () => {
      spyHelper.mockImplementation(() => throw new Error('Not Allowed')) // <-- this is working
      const res = await GetData('Brian')
      expect(res).toBeFalsy();
   })
})
```

Comment: what is `helper` ?

Comment: Is `checkIfUserAllowed` just globally accessible? How would the "function file" know it needs to call `helper.checkIfUserAllowed` instead of that seemingly global `checkIfUserAllowed`?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler its just naming, the point is i want to mock that function, so that the 'main' function run with mocked helper

Comment: @Cerbrus yes it is globally accessible. And i dont understand your question unfortunately

Comment: @GhafarizAinoorRohan can you add the complete test file here? You can also try to use `const mockFn = jest.fn(); jest.mock('<relativePath>/helper.ts', () => ({checkIfUserAllowed: () => mockFn() })); ... mockFn.mockResolveValue(...)` instead

Comment: @droebi YOU HELP ME ALOT. I dont know whats the problem behind jest.spyOn, but mock using this finally solve my problem! thank you